# SQL query for update statement in (C#)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am new to the C# programming. Facing the problem Incorrect syntax near 'First_Name'.! in the given below code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=HP\SQLEXPRESS100;Database=CD_Gallery;Integrated Security=true";
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Customer_Info First_Name ='" + fname.Text + "'");
            //'" + fname.Text.ToString() + "','" + lname.Text.ToString() + "','" + landmark.Text.ToString() + "','" + address.Text.ToString() + "','" + contact.Text.ToString() + "','" + email.Text.ToString() + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString() + "','" + deposite.Text.ToString() + "')", con);
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (a > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You Have Successfully Updated");
                Custid.Text = "";
                fname.Text = "";
                lname.Text = "";
                address.Text = "";
                contact.Text = "";
                email.Text = "";
                landmark.Text = "";
                deposite.Text = "";
            }
        }     
    }
```

Comment: yes this is not C# problem but you query is not correct.

Update table_Name SET column_Name = "Value";

Comment: Also: you should be using **parametrized queries** to avoid SQL Injection! Learn to write **good code** from the beginning - don't start writing sloppy code .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing SET keyword:

```
update Customer_Info SET First_Name ='" + fname.Text + "'"
```

and also provide `where` clause otherwise it will update all the records in your table.

Comment: Please can u tell me how to set where command.                     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Customer_Info First_Name ='" + fname.Text + "' where First_Name =..........

Comment: I am using datagridview in the form, so will the code should be in this manner SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Customer_Info First_Name ='" + fname.Text + "' where First_Name = '"+datagridview1.Selectedrow.Tostring()+"'";

Comment: "update Customer_Info SET First_Name ='" + fname.Text + "' where First_Name = '"+datagridview1.Selectedrow.Tostring()

Comment: if i have to update more then one attribute, then i have to try like SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Customer_Info SET First_Name ='" + fname.Text + "', Last_Name='" + lname.Text + "', Landmark='" + landmark.Text + "', Address='" + address.Text + "' WHERE First_Name ='" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "', Last_Name ='" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "', Landmark='" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "', Address='" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "'";

Answer (score 4):

**Problem :** You forgot to add word `SET` after your table name in update statement.

**Solution1 :** Add the word `SET` after table name in Update query **(Don't Recommend this)**

```
"update Customer_Info SET First_Name ='" + fname.Text + "'"
```

**Warning :** Your query is open to *sql injection attacks*.please use *parameterised queries* to avoid them

**Solution 2:** Using Parameterised Queries

Replace This:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Customer_Info SET First_Name 
                                                             ='"+fname.Text+"'");
```

With This:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Customer_Info First_Name = @fname");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname" , fname.Text);
```

Comment: After replacing the lines, the code is running but all customer's first names are getting replaced, Instead of replacing of the particular one.

Comment: I am using datagridview in the form.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem not in C#, in SQL syntax (you miss `set` keyword)

```
SqlCommand("update Customer_Info set First_Name ='" + fname.Text + "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing set keyword in query you have to place set like this

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Customer_Info set First_Name ='" + fname.Text + "'");
```